# Input text in a form and append a paired value to a search URL -

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a very rudimentary user of JavaScript and jQuery.

I have a form that builds a simple search URL based on user input, and uses the GET method to send the user to a set of filtered search results on a site at another domain. There is a base URL, and the form inputs are appended to it, as in

```
http://www.othersite.com/search.asp?q=input1&id=input2
```

My problem is that the other site uses an item ID in the search URL that is different than the item name. The users are going to know the item name, but the item ID is just a sequential key value.

I want to have the user enter the item name (along with some other input terms), and have the corresponding key value appended to the URL when it is submitted.

I have all the pairs of item names and IDs in a JSON file that I can format as needed. There are about 15,000 pairs.

So for example, the item named abc123 has an ID of 54321.
I want the user to enter abc123 in a text field, and to have `itemID=54321` appended to the base search URL.

I do not find any close examples I can borrow from.

Comment: So look up the key in the object and generate the url. If it is a form submission, set a hidden field.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So look up the id from the object and set a hidden field.

```js
var items = {
  "abc123" : 123456,
  "foo": 2345
}

document.getElementById("item").addEventListener("change", function () {
  var val = this.value;
  var id = items[val];
  if (!id) {
     alert("unknown product");
  }
  document.getElementById("itemID").value = id ? id : '';
})
```

```html
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemID" id="itemID" />
    <label for="item">Item: <label><input type="text" id="item" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This puts me on the right track. Can I store the data in a local file instead of putting all 15,000 pairs inside the script tags on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is too long of an answer. The below method uses the datalist element along with an input list element that gets populated with an xhr request. Also, don't forget that Safari doesn't do datalists :(... User beware this hasn't been tested.

---

```
<form id='search-form' method='GET'>
    <input list='search-data' 
      name='item-title'
      id='search-input' 
      value='' 
      placeholder='Search Titles'>
    <datalist id='search-data'>
    </datalist>
    <input type='submit' name='submit-search' />
</form>
```

---

```
// Encapsulate a function
// Load JSON using XHR and than append
// an options node element to the list input.
(function searchFormScoped(){
var _form = document.getElementById("search-form"),
    _listNode = document.getElementById("search-data");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/the_request_url.json");
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.onload = function loadHtmlFormList(e) {
    var _data = this.response,
        _datakeys = Object.keys(_data);
    // loop through key id's and populate the option with 
      // the correct values and data attributes
    for(var c=0; c < _datakeys.length; c++) {
    var _opt = document.createElement("options");
        // store the key values from the json as the options value 
        _opt.value = _data[_datakeys[c]];
        // I use the data-id attribute to store key values of the json
        _opt.setAttribute('data-id', _datakeys[c]);
    }

    // Set an event to be executed when the list value changes
    _listNode.addEventListener("change", function searchOptionChanged(e) {
      var _infoNode = _listNode.querySelector('option[value="' + e.target.value + '"]');
      // Set the data-item attribute of the target event element of the 
        // string you need for your search string url to use for when the form is
        // submitted, or from here you could set the action attribute, I believe.
      e.target.setAttribute('data-item', 'itemID=' +_infoNode.getAttribute('data-id'));
    });

  }
  xhr.send(); 
})();
```

Comment: Also, I forgot to set up a hidden input form item like in @epascarello's example, if you wanted to set the hidden items value to the item url for you server script.